# How to push down the text printed in the current row in command prompt? (Python 3.8 on Windows)

Tags: python, multithreading, ansi-escape

Taking into consideration the following program:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


def speaker():
    while True:
        sleep(3)
        print("[*]I'm speaking........")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_speaker = Thread(target=speaker)
    my_speaker.start()
    while True:
        msg = input("[Your message]>> ")
        print("Your message: " + msg)
```

Output if i don't type anything in input ('_' is the position of the cursor):

```
[Your message]>> [*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
_
```

Output i'd like to show:

```
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[*]I'm speaking........
[Your message]>> _
```

When the 'speaker' function executes the print function it should perform the following steps:

- Move the text of the current line to the next line
- Return to the beginning of the previous line
- Perform the print
- Return to the end of the next line

I took a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences
and I found some useful things like being able to go back to the beginning of the current line with '**\r**', however I don't want to overwrite the text but move it to the next line.

Some idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


def speaker():
    while True:
        sleep(3)
        print("\r[*]I'm speaking........\n[Your message]>> ", end="")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_speaker = Thread(target=speaker)
    my_speaker.start()
    while True:
        msg = input("[Your message]>> ")
        print("Your message: " + msg)
```

Comment: I also tried this solution, it works if you are not writing anything to the input and the problem is just that:

`[*]I'm speaking........\n
[Your message]>> Hello wo`

If the 'speaker' function executes the print function right now it will overwrite "Hello wo".

Comment: Not sure what did you mean. Everything seems to be working properly on mine. I did typing 'Hello wo' in the first '[Your message]' showing, and it prints 'Your message: Hello wo' in the next line. And the speaker() also keeps running... Also works perfectly when I don't insert anything as an input.

Comment: So I guess if that's a limitation that is owned by the Windows Command Prompt. Sorry, can't reproduce this as my OS only Linux. Hopefully, this link will help you: https://superuser.com/questions/1325654/inserting-r-n-into-parameter-on-windows

Comment: Thank you for the answers and the link.
Sorry if I haven't been clear in explaining the problem, what I mean is this:
If you try to type "Hello wo" and wait for the speaker () function to run without pressing enter the print function will overwrite "Hello wo" even if the string is not yet saved in msg.
So, if you try to write "rld" and then press enter msg will contain the string "Hello world" even if you have apparently typed only "rld".

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found is that the place for sleep(3) was making your input to appear before you wanted, since what you wanted to wait was the input itself.

The next problem is that if you do so, your input would be in the end, but it would also show you something like "[Your message]>> [*]I'm speaking........". I think this is because you're executing the input and the loop almost at the same time, and it kind of "turns crazy" so I added that simple opt trigger to prevent the print from working and finally getting the input to the lower part withouth any strange outcome.

This is a simple and rough solution to your problem.

I don't consider it to be perfect and I'm pretty sure there's a better option to solve this. I'm a newbie myself too to coding, but I hope my solution comes you in handy!

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread



def speaker():
    while True:
        if opt is not None:
            print ("[*]I'm speaking........")
global opt                   
opt = 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_speaker = Thread(target=speaker)
    my_speaker.start()
    while True:
        sleep(3)
        opt = None
        msg = input("[Your message]>> ")
        print("Your message: " + msg)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the question is not when to print `[*]I'm speaking........`, but how to format the text correctly in the terminal when i'm writing something in input and the 'speaker' function executes the print.